# Does Pandas have notin function to filter rows from data frame from a given list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and I need to get the rows which are `"no in"` the given list
I know in order to get the rows from the list we can use `isin.(list)`, so my question is whether there is a contrary  "notin" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `~` in front of condition to negate it.

```
~df['Col1'].isin(list)
```

`df['Col1'].isin(list)` will return True/False, then just flip the boolean to get True where `Col1` is not in the list.